# Sherlock Holmes argparse module task

Tags: python, command-line, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argparse

I've been given a task that seems over my current capabilities with python. Nonetheless, I do want to solve it, but don't know where to begin. Especially this bit here: "write a program that takes a file as an argument, reads it, decodes it, and prints the decoded text". Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Task description:**

Professor Moriarty is causing trouble again! Mary managed to get a file with a piece of his plan, but it's encoded. Before she could decode it, Moriarty had taken her hostage and Dr. Watson went to the rescue.

Holmes anticipated that and found a simple Caesar cipher decoder on Stackoverflow to deal with it himself:

```
def decode_Caesar_cipher(s, n):
    alpha = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',.?!"
    s = s.strip()
    text = ''
    for c in s:
        text += alpha[(alpha.index(c) + n) % len(alpha)]
    print('Decoded text: "' + text + '"')
```

However, Holmes doesn't know how to work with files, so you must help him! Below you find the file Mary got from Moriarty's laptop. Download it and, using the code Holmes found, write a program that takes a file as an argument, reads it, decodes it, and prints the decoded text. To do that, use your IDE. When you get the answer, copy it and paste it into the answer field.

If your argument `--file` is stored in the variable `args`, you can read the file you've passed to your script this way:

```
filename = args.file
opened_file = open(filename)
encoded_text = opened_file.read()  # read the file into a string
opened_file.close()  # always close the files you've opened
```

Hint 1: Initially the file Holmes got from Mary was called "13.txt", so he presupposed that this might be the offset `n`. Check this theory but keep in mind that for decoding the offset has to be taken with a minus.

Hint 2: Set up the command line to quickly cycle through many key/'n' arguments. Once you find the decoded message, paste that into the answer field without quotes.

Hint 3: You don't need use argsparser, the main problem is to find "n".

Dataset can be downloaded from [this link](https://filebin.net/2zpmcxq3nuamrwjd/dataset_copy.txt?t=1w7615a2)

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mre]. See also [homework guidance.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the `argparse` Python standard library. It can used as follows in your case:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Path to file")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then in your e.g. `main` function you can access the argument as follows:

```py
file = args.file
```

And you would call the program as so:

```
python your_program.py --file filename/or/path/to/file
```

In Python I would recommend running the program in the same directory (folder) as the file is in.
Now you have the *name* of the file in a variable and can load it how you like.

---

EDIT:
So in the end, your program structure could look like this:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Path to file")
args = parser.parse_args()

def read_file(filename):
    opened_file = open(filename)
    encoded_text = opened_file.read()  # read the file into a string
    opened_file.close()  # always close the files you've opened
    return encoded_text

def decode_Caesar_cipher(s, n):
    alpha = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',.?!"
    s = s.strip()
    text = ''
    for c in s:
        text += alpha[(alpha.index(c) + n) % len(alpha)]
    print('Decoded text: "' + text + '"')

def main():
    filename = args.file
    encoded_text = read_file(filename)
    # Note that before calling decode_Caesar_cipher, you need to determine 'n',
    # which seems to be the main task for this programming challenge.
    # This can be achieved with e.g. a for loop
    for n in range(1, 30):
        print("n =", n, end=", ")
        decode_Caesar_cipher(encoded_text, n)
        print("n = -", n, sep="", end=", ")
        decode_Caesar_cipher(encoded_text, -n)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Aarni, thanks for your feedback.

Just so I understand this better, at which point do I run the decoder?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a bit more program structure to help you advance. Look at the `main` function, there is the order in which the example program executes other functions.

Comment: Aarni, I'm super grateful for the edit you added. Highly appreciate it! 

I know this might sound weird, but I've never used an IDE before, so I'm a bit lost. I can understand - to some degree - the program structure you posted, but how exactly to run on an IDE is a roadblock.

This challenge is tough because it was posted today and the deadline is today as well (still a couple of hours left). I was thinking: can I simply paste the encoded text (will post it in the next comment due to character number limitation) inside the program and skip the process of opening and reading the file?

Comment: The downloaded file with the encoded text:
`Qrn!Mfur!y,pxIMvsMF,BH!rM!rnqv'tMAuv IMAur'JJJMVHzMCr!FIMCr!FMqv n..,v'ArqJMQvqMF,BM!rnyyFMAuv'xMVMD,ByqMB rMAurMPrn r!Mpv.ur!MA,Mr'p,qrMzFMrCvyM.yn'KMc,,!MAuv'tLMjur'MqvqMF,BM A,.MB v'tMF,B!Mo!nv'KMOr AMDv ur IMZ,!vn!AF
`

Determining n happens inside the decoder function, right?

Comment: You basically run your program from a console like this: `python your_program_name.py --file name_of_deciphered_file.txt`. In your IDE, find the console and type this command. You can also use a command prompt, e.g. "Command Prompt" in Windows. Determining `n` happens outside of the decoder function because as you see, the decipher function takes exactly one n as a parameter. From what I understand, you should not paste the text inside the program, because it is explicitly instructed to be loaded from a command-line argument.

Comment: Spoiler alert: There was a hint in the instructions that the value of `n` might be negative 13, which gives an output of: `Decoded text: "Dear Sherlock, if you're reading this, then... I'm very, very disappointed. Did you really think I would use the Ceaser cipher to encode my evil plan? Poor thing! When did you stop using your brain? Best wishes, Moriarty"`. However, you probably should make a `for` loop that runs the decipher function with different values of `n` to achieve what I assume to be the purpose of this challenge.

Comment: Aarni, super super thank you for all your detailed explanations! It worked!

Comment: No problem! You definitely should study a little bit about how the program works to understand what exactly is happening. Best of luck :)